# Java: Aggregate Operations

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, functional-interface

I'm studying generics, functional interfaces, lambda expressions, and aggregate operations. Although I understand these technologies individually, I'm having trouble conceptualizing them collectively, i.e., how they work together.

Using an example taken from the Java Doc titled: **interface Collector(T,A,R)**:

```
Collector(Widget,?,TreeSet(Widget)) into = Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::add, (left,right)->{left.addAll(right); return left;});
```

The above method, in the aforementioned javadoc, has the following behavioral parameters:

```
Supplier(A) supplier,
BiConsumer(A,T) accumulator,
BiConsumer(A) combiner
```

The supplier provided in the above example uses the method reference: `TreeSet::new`.

What is the relationship of the `TreeSet::new`, being used as the supplier of results, to the accumulator?..to that of the combiner?

How does this work, I don't understand how this is a supplier!?

Any documentation links concerning this broad subject matter would be worth much gold and silver. 
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'm new to the site and learning the ins and outs. It appears that you have edited my question. Is that so? and if so, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Quotes directly from the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

The Supplier:

> A function that creates and returns a new mutable result container.

The `TreeSet::new` is just a call to the constructor of TreeSet, which returns an instance of TreeSet. In this sense it is a supplier of TreeSets.

The BiConsumer, called the accumulator in this context, represents

> A function that folds a value into a mutable result container.

It will offer objects of type T to the object of type A. Typically you will just call some `add` method of a collection, but you can also do some pre-processing here when defining a custom collector.

Lastly the BiConsumer is described as:

> A function that accepts two partial results and merges them.

It is used when a process is executed in parallel and partial results (in this context, `TreeSet` objects with only a subset of the elements) need to be combined into the final `TreeSet` result. This would typically be an `addAll` method.

So by providing these necessary ingredients, you are able to construct your own collection mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Boris, your explanation of each function was what I needed to read. You have helped me to have a deeper understanding of these technologies.